# Can I store data in RAM with Apache Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I would like to know if it is possible to store a bunch of strings, for example, in RAM with Apache Spark. Indeed, I want to query and update these strings depending the new input data that Apache Spark is treating. Futhermore, if it is possible, can a node notify all other nodes which strings are stored ?
If you need information about my projet, feel free to ask.

J

Comment: Question is quite broad... Spark is not a database engine or any other storage, it's a computation engine. Consider Data Grids (Apache Ignite, Hazelcast, Oracle Coherence, etc), they are in-RAM storage with option to update data. Spark can load data, process, even save in Hive tables. Currently we have not much information about use case

Comment: I know Spark is not a database. Actually, I want to save some information about current processed data in order to do mathematical operations on future data with information I previously stored in RAM...Regarding Hive tables, can you tell me more about that ? is a table independent for each node, or common for all nodes ? where is it stored ?

Comment: If you have workflow as: load -> transform -> transform again -> etc -> write results, then you can read data to DataFrame, cache it to RAM an then perform calculation. You will have option to read data and - as far as I know from Spark 2.0 - update it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need the stateful streaming function `mapWithState`. This function allows you to update state cached in memory across streaming batches.

Note that you will need to enable checkpointing if you haven't already done so.

Scala example usage:

```
def stateUpdateFunction(userId: UserId,
                        newData: UserAction,
                        stateData: State[UserSession]): UserModel = {
    val currentSession = stateData.get()    // Get current session data
    val updatedSession = ...            // Compute updated session using newData
    stateData.update(updatedSession)            // Update session data     
    val userModel = ...                 // Compute model using updatedSession
    return userModel                // Send model downstream
}

// Stream of user actions, keyed by the user ID
val userActions = ...  // stream of key-value tuples of (UserId, UserAction)
// Stream of data to commit
val userModels = userActions.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(stateUpdateFunction))
```

https://databricks.com/blog/2016/02/01/faster-stateful-stream-processing-in-apache-spark-streaming.html

Java example usage:

```
// Update the cumulative count function
Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>> mappingFunc =
    new Function3<String, Optional<Integer>, State<Integer>, Tuple2<String, Integer>>() {
      @Override
      public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String word, Optional<Integer> one,
          State<Integer> state) {
        int sum = one.orElse(0) + (state.exists() ? state.get() : 0);
        Tuple2<String, Integer> output = new Tuple2<>(word, sum);
        state.update(sum);
        return output;
      }
    };

// DStream made of get cumulative counts that get updated in every batch
JavaMapWithStateDStream<String, Integer, Integer, Tuple2<String, Integer>> stateDstream =
    wordsDstream.mapWithState(StateSpec.function(mappingFunc).initialState(initialRDD));
```

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/JavaStatefulNetworkWordCount.java line 90:

Comment: Thanks ImDarrenG, do you know if there is an example in Java ?

Comment: Thanks ImDarrenG, I fully understand how to use mapWithMap. However, I have a question. Imagine I have this json line {"device":"dv1","parameter1":"vv1","parameter2":"vv2"}

With the following example + my code to parse json, I can ingrement the number of time dv1 appears. And the result displayed is for instance (dv1, 51).

Now, i want to include the result in the json line in order to get in output:
{"device":"dv1","parameter1":"vv1","parameter2":"vv2","increment":51}

Do you have an idea how I can achieve that ? I don't see how I can make it with the previous code.

Comment: Sounds like you need poco objects to represent the state of each line. mapWithState would do the incrementing on the collection of those objects which are cache across batches.  Then you can serialise to JSON when you need to output.

Comment: ok, i am not very familiar with Pojo, do you have an example I can take into account.

Comment: As in a Java class with properties for device, increment and whatever else your JSON object has, to make working with state easier than manipulating json encoded strings.